# Big transaction (multiple inserts) exceed RAM size : what happens?

Tags: postgresql

I do multiple inserts in single transaction that exceed RAM size:

I learned that inserts (delete) are written in RAM and that modified pages became dirty pages.

But what happen if dirty pages exceed RAM size: Checkpoint writes dirty pages on disk before the end of transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry.

PostgreSQL caches 8kB pages of disk storage in RAM when the data are read or written, but modified (“dirty”) pages in the cache (shared buffers) are automatically written out to disk by the database system.

Normally, this happens during a *checkpoint*, but there is also a special background process, the *background writer*, that keeps writing out dirty pages from the cache so that there are always some clean pages in the cache that clients can use.

In the unlikely event that despite all that there is still no clean page to be found, the backend process that needs some cache space can clean out a dirty page itself. So, no matter what, you will always get some cache space eventually.

It also doesn't matter if your transaction is large or not. PostgreSQL doesn't wait for the transaction to be committed before it writes out data to disk, it will happily persist uncommitted data modifications from an active transaction. If the transaction fails, these data will just be rendered invisible (“dead”).

Owing to PostgreSQL architecture, your transaction will never fail just because it changes too many data.

Comment: Thanks, so dirty pages are written to disk during big transaction is in progress ! And for WAls ? They are written to disk during big transaction is in progress : See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39879754/13811001)

Comment: Yes, WAL is also regularly written to disk, even if no transaction commits.